# JWT token validation process in AdonisJs / Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, token, jwt, adonis.js

I am using `AdonisJs` which is very similar to `Laravel` except syntax. I have generated `JWT` token with User Model providing `uid` as email and `password` as password as below;

```
jwt: {
    serializer: 'lucid',
    model: 'App/Models/User',
    scheme: 'jwt',
    uid: 'email',
    password: 'password',
    options: {
      secret: Env.get('APP_KEY'),
      expiresIn: 1000000000,
    }
  }
```

I was able to get user by validating that token through API call with postman.

Now I have changed the `email` id from database manually which was `uid` while generating token previously, I am still able to validate previous token and get user details through postman api call.

My question is, Adonis  `auth` object should be validating that token when `await.auth.getUser()` is called. but instead of invaliding, this returning data with updated email which was changed manually from database. How does this process work? I guess this will be same in Laravel.

Comment: What does this have to do with laravel?

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz `Lravel` deals the `auth` in similar way, concept of Larvel will be helpful for me to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answer on [forum.adonisjs.com](https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/validating-auth-token-when-credentials-change/6359/6?u=crbast)*

Adonis uses **only** the user ID for authentication.

Basic Adonis token : 
[image]
[*full token*](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOjEsImlhdCI6MTU4ODg1NTU3NH0.7LowalMfdEg5lvUZPNFkOAL_7QHRPi10Hk8sjvJ1Hm0)

uid = user ID

**You can encode the `User` object into the token with `jwtPayload` and then manually check `User` data:**

### Add User instance in Payload

Enable [jwtPayload](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/authentication#_generateuser_jwtpayload_jwtoptions) when create token:

```js
const user = await User.find(1)

// generate(user, [jwtPayload], [jwtOptions])
const token = await auth.generate(user, true)
```

#### Token example:

[image]
[*full token*](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1aWQiOjIsImRhdGEiOnsiZW1haWwiOiJ0ZXN0QGNyYmFzdC5jaCIsInJvbGUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImNyZWF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDIwLTA1LTA2IDExOjI2OjM2IiwidXBkYXRlZF9hdCI6IjIwMjAtMDUtMDYgMTE6MjY6MzYiLCJpZCI6Mn0sImlhdCI6MTU4ODc1NzE5Nn0.J93frgdDNtb7t3kEgPxAbe41Qzw_uif1OUUVGbc4vao)

### Get Payload data

```js
const data = auth.jwtPayload; // Get full Playload

const user = auth.jwtPayload.data; // Get user
```

Output (full Payload) :

```
{
  "uid": 2,
  "data": {
    "email": "test@crbast.ch",
    "role": "admin",
    "created_at": "2020-05-06 11:26:36",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-06 11:26:36",
    "id": 2
  },
  "iat": 1588757196
}
```

### Now you can validate email